# Как округлить число

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, ecmascript, округление

Есть способ округления числа.. Вот есть число 0.9708333333333333, как его округлить до 0.97? Нужно сделать это во флеше, но меток поставил больше, так как думаю, везде будет одинаково.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо во флеше только с костылями: [Rounding to specific decimal places in Flash](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/rounding-specific-decimal-places-flash.html)

```
 Code                     | Number of Decimal Places | Example Results
--------------------------|--------------------------|-----------------
 Math.round(20/7);        | none                     | 3
 int((20/7)*10)/10;       | 1                        | 2.8
 int((20/7)*100)/100;     | 2                        | 2.85
 int((20/7)*1000)/1000;   | 3                        | 2.857
 int((20/7)*10000)/10000; | 4                        | 2.85 71
```

Comment: Это вполне нормальный метод

Answer (score 1):

В JavaScript округляется так:
http://javascript.ru/Number/toFixed

```
var n = 12345.6789;
n.toFixed();              // 12346: округление, длина дробной части ноль
n.toFixed(1);             // 12345.7: округление 
n.toFixed(6);             // 12345.678900: добили нулями
(1.23e+20).toFixed(2);    // 123000000000000000000.00
(1.23e-10).toFixed(2)     // 0.00
```

Comment: @HA3IK: Спасибо! я знал про этот способ, но не получалось, так как забыл об ещё одной паре скобок. Спасибо!

Comment: @HA3IK, это не единственный способ округления в JS. Есть еще toPrecision() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision И кстати, на javascript.ru не очень качественная и устаревшая информация. Например здесь http://javascript.ru/math.round в описании метода новичку придется догадаться, что метод округляет число. Сравните с описанием здесь https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round